# How can a thread in a separat class passes data to the main class

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I wrote the below code, and my problem is that, I want to pass data from the FICSR class to the main class. I tried to declare the ArrayList "mentioned inside the calcFICS() method" in the constructor of the FICSR class but after that I found that I could not use them inside
the calcFICS() method, why?? and how to solve it.

**MainClass**:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MatFactory matFactory = new MatFactory();
    FilePathUtils.addInputPath(path_Obj);
    Mat bgrMat = matFactory.newMat(FilePathUtils.getInputFileFullPathList().get(0));

    if (bgrMat != null) {
        if (!bgrMat.empty()) {
            fiCSR = new FICSR(bgrMat, SysConsts.MIN_CS_RADIUS);
        } else {
            Log.E(TAG, "MainClass", "bgrMat is empty");
        }
    } else {
        Log.E(TAG, "MainClass", "bgrMat is null");
    }
```

**FICSR class**:

```
    public FICSR(Mat bgrMat, int csRadius) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.bgrMat = bgrMat;
    this.csRadius = csRadius;

    this.fiCS_R3 = new Thread(new FICS(this.bgrMat, this.csRadius), "FICS_R" + this.csRadius);
    fiCS_R3.start();
}

    private class FICS implements Runnable {

    private Mat bgrMat;
    private int csRadius;

    public FICS(Mat bgrMat, int csRadius) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.bgrMat = bgrMat;
        this.csRadius = csRadius;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        calcFICS(this.bgrMat, this.csRadius);
    }

    public static void calcFICS(Mat bgrMat, int csRadius) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Mat> onOffCSActRegMatsList = null;
    ArrayList<Mat> offOnCSActRegMatsList = null;

    ArrayList<Mat> onOffCSFullMatsList = null;
    ArrayList<Mat> offOnCSFullMatsList = null;

    onOffCSActRegMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    offOnCSActRegMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    onOffCSFullMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    offOnCSFullMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    //here I want to add values to the ArrayLists defined above and return them to the main class. how can I do that?
```

...
...
...

Comment: are these 2 classes in same package?

Comment: @AADTechnical yes...does if they are in the same cpackage, would that could be helpfull??

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it because calcFICS is static and you can't access non static fields from a static method.
But if you want to do calculations in worker threads to make use of all CPU cores, a better solution is to use an ExecutorService, e.g. a ForkJoinPool.

**FICS class:**

```
class FICS {
  static class Result {
    ArrayList<Mat> onOffCSActRegMatsList;
    ArrayList<Mat> offOnCSActRegMatsList;
    ArrayList<Mat> onOffCSFullMatsList;
    ArrayList<Mat> offOnCSFullMatsList;
  }

  public static Result calcFICS(Mat bgrMat, int csRadius) {
    Result result = new Result();
    result.onOffCSActRegMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    result.offOnCSActRegMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    result.onOffCSFullMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    result.offOnCSFullMatsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    //add values to the ArrayLists
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
...
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
Future<FICS.Result> fut = pool.submit(() -> FICS.calcFICS(bgrMat, SysConsts.MIN_CS_RADIUS));
FICS.Result result = fut.get();
...
```

fut.get() will block the main thread until the calculation is finished. But you can submit several calculations to the pool before calling any get method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class level variable, with getters and setters, keep appending the values to it and in the main method use the getter to retrieve the value.

Comment: do u mean inside the FICS class or the FICSR class, because i tried to declare the lists inside the FICS class and they are not accessibe inside the calcFICS() method